# How can I have Visual Studio 2008 server still server site while not debugging?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, iis

In Visual Studio 2008, I'd like to have the internal web server still serve my website on the designated port even after I've stopped debugging.  In other words, if my site runs on localhost:2923 once I begin debugging, after I stop debugging I'd still like to go there to have the site run (not in debug mode).

Sometimes this works and sometimes this doesn't.  Is there a setting per project in VS2008 to change this?

Thanks!
-kc

Answer (score 2):

After you have run debugging once and not exited VS it should allow you to use that localhost port till you close down VS. At least that has been my experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just install IIS and have it serve up the web as well?  There's no reason that IIS and the dev server can't serve from the same directory...   And at that point, you don't even need the development server - you can configure your project to run under IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I would use "Detach All" instead of "Stop Debugging". That will stop VS2008 from debugging the site, but will keep your site running.

You could also Reattach and continue debugging if you ever need to.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

Right-click the project you want to run in Solution Explorer, select *Debug*, and *Start new instance*.

You can close the web browser that is launched for debugging and you're returned to Visual Studio in non-debugging mode, but the internal web server is still running.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer...

Right-click on your project and go to Properties.  Under "Web", turn off "Enable Edit and Continue" and now when you stop debugging, your port still persists the site.